# Django: Show reverse ForeignKey lookup on admin page, as read-only list?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to show a reverse ForeignKey lookup on a Django admin page, and make it read-only, as a lightweight list of strings.

The standard way to do this seems to be with an inline admin field, but I don't want it to be editable, so I wonder if there's a lighter-weight way to do it.

These are my fields:

```
class Book: 
  title = models.TextField(blank=True)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Author: 
  name = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

On the admin change/delete page for an author, I'd like to show a read-only list of their books.

I can do this with an `admin.StackedInline`, but it's quite cumbersome to make it read-only:

```
class BooksInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Book
  fields = ('title',)
  readonly_fields = ('title',)

  def has_add_permission(request, obj):
    return False

  def has_delete_permission(request, obj, self):
    return False
```

And the resulting list takes up a lot of space on the page, because the design expects it all to be editable.

Is there a simpler way to make a read-only list?

Comment: After 3 hours of googling I didn't find the solution of this problem. I'm confused.

Answer (score 11):

I didn't like the idea of having admin-only logic in the model and I didn't like the idea of mucking with the templates if I didn't need to, so I instead implemented this in the admin.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('books_list')
    fields = ('name', 'books_list')

    def books_list(self, obj):
        books = Book.objects.filter(author=obj)
        if books.count() == 0:
            return '(None)'
        output = ', '.join([unicode(book) for book in books])
        return output
    books_list.short_description = 'Book(s)'
```

For bonus points, we can make each book link to the change page for that book.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.utils.html import format_html

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('books_list')
    fields = ('name', 'books_list')

    def books_list(self, obj):
        books = Book.objects.filter(author=obj)
        if books.count() == 0:
            return '(None)'
        book_links = []
        for book in books:
            change_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:myapp_book_change', args=(book.id,))
            book_links.append('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (change_url, unicode(book))
        return format_html(', '.join(book_links))
    books_list.allow_tags = True
    books_list.short_description = 'Book(s)'
```

Double bonus, you can encapsulate this into a function so that you don't have to rewrite this logic everytime you want to show a list of reverse foreignkey objects in Admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.utils.html import format_html

def reverse_foreignkey_change_links(model, get_instances, description=None, get_link_html=None, empty_text='(None)'):
    if not description:
        description = model.__name__ + '(s)'

    def model_change_link_function(_, obj):
        instances = get_instances(obj)
        if instances.count() == 0:
            return empty_text
        output = ''
        links = []
        for instance in instances:
            change_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:%s_change' % model._meta.db_table, args=(instance.id,))
            links.append('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (change_url, unicode(instance))
        return format_html(', '.join(links))

    model_change_link_function.short_description = description
    model_change_link_function.allow_tags = True
    return model_change_link_function

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('books_list')
    fields = ('name', 'books_list')

    def books_list = reverse_foreignkey_change_links(Book, lambda obj: Book.objects.filter(author=obj))
```

Comment: Note that you can also put this in list_display as well, if you so desire! `list_display = ('name', 'books_list')`

Comment: Awesome. Still works in 2.x, except that the `reverse()` function moved somewhere else. Also I changed `instance.id` to `instance.pk` as our models use UUIDs for primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a class method as mentioned in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) and use the _set related reverse lookup described in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

The list result is read only, so there is no need to do checking in the Admin.

```
// models.py
class Book: 
  title = models.TextField(blank=True)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Author: 
  name = models.TextField(blank=True)

  def get_author_books(self):
      cur_books = self.book_set.all()
      books = [b.title for b in cur_books]
      return books

  get_author_books.short_description = "Author's Books"


// admin.py
class BooksInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Book
  fields = ('title','get_author_books')
```

Comment: cur_books = self.book_set.all() didnt work for me. Any help? I am using django 3.x. I also wanted to do a count of all books for a author like this - cur_books = self.book_set.all().filter(author=self.name).count(). The authoradmin complains there is no self.name and there is no book_set object

Comment: `get_author_books` needs to be added as well to the `readonly_fileds` list


`readonly_fields = ('get_author_books',)

fields = ('title', 'get_author_books')`

Answer (score 0):

I would normally do this by overriding the admin template. That's because this is mainly about presentation logic (but you may want to manipulate the queryset in the ModelAdmin to use `prefetch_related()`). Create a file `myapp/templates/admin/myapp/mymodel/change_form.html`. In the file, put:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_materials %}

{% block content %}
{% if change %}
<div class="author-list">
    <h1>{% trans "Authors" %}</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for author in original.author_set.all %}
        <li>{{ author.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}

{{ block.super }}

{% endblock %}
```

This is compatible with standard django.contrib.admin and django-suit... I can't say if more exotic admin skins like django-grappelli modifies the admin template block names.